# По нажатию Button отключить свойство Form1 Resize

Tags: c#, winforms

В `Form1_Resize` есть функции которые меняют вид компонентов при изменении размера формы/фрейма. Как по нажатию на `Button` отключить `Form1_Resize` чтобы его код не срабатывал?

Comment: ...сделать отписку от события

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button_Click` вешается на кнопку. В обработчике отписываемся от события [`Control.Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Resize -= Form1_Resize;
}
```

Для подписки на событие ресайза:

```
    Resize += Form1_Resize;
```

---

Так же в нестабильном коде существует практика при подписки на событие сначала отписываться от него (чтобы предотвратить двойную подписку):

```
    Resize -= Form1_Resize;
    Resize += Form1_Resize;
```

Comment: То есть если нужно обратно включить, то Resize += Form1_Resize;?

Comment: @Kaya  в яблочко!

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool _ResizeFlag = true;

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!_ResizeFlag)
    return;

  ...
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _ResizeFlag = false;
}
```